# how to execute a function when loading a page in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Best regards, I have a problem with a component, which is divided into app.component and its respective .html, I need a function to be executed when loading the page, when loading the modal that I have in this component, I tried with `$ (document) .ready ()`, but it didn't work, I think it's a problem in the way I make the call, I don't understand very well how it still works,

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
   <a class="boton grande intermedio"  ng-touchstart="$ctrl.listConve()">Validar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I need to load it in this select:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
   <select class="form-control" id="convenio" name="selectConvenio"
           placeholder="Convenio" >
    <option selected>Elegir Convenio...</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in $ctr.dataList">{{$option.nombreConvenio}}</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

intente llamarlo de esta forma:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
   function(){
     alert('funciona');
     $ctrl.listConve()
   })
</script>
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: For loading data on load, you would normally use `ng-init` for example `<div class="row" ng-init="listConve()">`. But it looks like you have some syntax errors, for example you shouldnt need `$` in the view so `$option.nombreConvenio` should be `option.nombreConvenio`

Comment: Please add your controller's code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$onInit` life-cycle hook in the controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function() {
    this.listConve = function() {
        //...
    };

    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.listConve();
    };
})
```

From the Docs:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onInit()` - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

Comment: The solution was perfect, I had done it with an ng-init, but I read in several blogs that this should not be done.
Thanks a lot.